# Make variable visible outside loop

Tags: java

I'm new to java, im just getting used to it. I don't know how to make a variable seen outside a if statement. In one of my methods, I created an array inside a if statement and want it to be seen outside the if statement too. I don't seem to know how to do this. I tried the following but it is not working.

Comment: I think you should have a look at variable scope rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change

```
 if(i==1){
  int[] temp; // this temp array visible only inside if
  temp = new int[7];
 }
 temp[i] = temperature;
```

To

```
 int[] temp=null; // initialize temp array out side if
 if(i==1){       
   temp =new int[7] 
 }
 temp[i] = temperature;
```

In second case `temp` is define out side the `if`, So your `temp` array visible inside `for` loop.

Edit:  Read About [variable scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm). You can find more info [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).

Comment: This worked thank you. Could you please tell me why this solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable in the "scope" you want it to be available for edit/read.

If you want it to be available outside of the if statement as well, then declare it at the beginning of the method (outside if statement).

```
public void readTemperature(int i, int temperature) {
     int[] temp = null; 
       // temp variable will be available in "smaller scopes" anywhere inside 
       // the method even within control logic statement (if else) or loops such as 
       // for/while
     if(i==1){       
         temp =new int[7] 
     }
     if (temp != null) // you may want to add this check
         temp[i] = temperature;
     }
 }
```

Not completely related but [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) might help article to read.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the array from outside the if statement. You can follow both ways.

```
int[] temp = null; 
if(i==1){       
    temp =new int[7] 
}


int[] temp; 
if(i==1){       
    temp =new int[7] 
}
```

first one must be null check before use it. second one gives compiler error to initialize. So you can add else clause and set empty array.